# Egit, switch branch, merge

Tags: git, merge, branch, egit

I got my main app branch: 'development'. My friend work on it, and commit his changes. My branch is 'development2'. I work on it commit changes and sometimes merge with 'development'. But now I commit all changes (merged with 'development' branch), my task is to merge all my changes from 'development2' to 'development'. I commit all changes, and switched to 'development', but now I can't maerge (with 'development2') because I get:
[image: communicat]

Please, exaplain me what's wrong, and how to merge 'development2' into 'development'

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  Your working directory is dirty, and peforming the merge would possibly overwrite some of your uncommitted work.  Have you tried typing `git status` from the bash?

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you experience is related to some changes you've made in working directory. These changes may or may not be staged at this point. The `git` system is telling you

> If you merge at this point, you will lose your work. so, please either
>   reset, stash or commit your work prior to merge.

The system is besically protecting you from losing your work.

What you could do at this point is either add and commit whatever has been modified.

```
git add <...>
git commit -m "..."
```

Alternatively, you can stash your work using

```
git stash
```

and it will *stash* everything for later use. Or, you can also *reset* work to current index using

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Note, make sure you understand what you are doing at this point and what are the implications.